# Elasticsearch standard analyser stopwords

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to guess what is the default stopwords list in standard analyzer in elasticsearch. I run version 1.3.1, and it seems to me that the English list is used, because running a wildcard query like this

```
{
      "wildcard" : {
        "name" : {
          "wildcard" : "*in*"
        }
      }
}
```

Gives me no results (I sure have documents names containing "in", and they are returned when using not_analyzed mapping). However, on the [1.0 breaking changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_stopwords.html) they say the default is now Empty, and the same is stated in the [Standard Analyzer documentation for the latest version](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html). On the other hand, when clicking on the given link for more details, i end up to the [Stop Analyzer documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-analyzer.html), saying that the default is still English.

Any Help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the list of stopwords for the standard analyzer: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/4.9.0/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/StopAnalyzer.java?av=f#50

```
50   static {
51     final List<String> stopWords = Arrays.asList(
52       "a", "an", "and", "are", "as", "at", "be", "but", "by",
53       "for", "if", "in", "into", "is", "it",
54       "no", "not", "of", "on", "or", "such",
55       "that", "the", "their", "then", "there", "these",
56       "they", "this", "to", "was", "will", "with"
57     );
58     final CharArraySet stopSet = new CharArraySet(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, 
59         stopWords, false);
60     ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET = CharArraySet.unmodifiableSet(stopSet); 
61   }
```

Elasticsearch source code for `standard`: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v1.3.1/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/analysis/StandardAnalyzerProvider.java#L47

Which links to Lucene's `StandardAnalyzer`, which in turn references `StopAnalyzer`'s stopwords list: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/4.9.0/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.java?av=f#63